# Convert JSON to CSV in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a problem with converting JSON to CSV.
JSON looks like that:

```json
{
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value3",
  "Key3": "Value2",
  ...
}
```

And I expect the CSV in this format:

```
Key, Value
Key1, Value1
Key2, Value2
Key3, Value3
...
```

As you see keys and values are stored in column. Is it possible to do that in data flow in Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using Azure data factory **Data flow** `Unpivot` transformation.

Please see the below **repro** details.

**Input:**

[image]

**Data flow:**

1. Add **`Source`** and connect it to the JSON Input file. In source options under JSON settings, select the document form as **Single document**.

[image]

**Source Data preview:**

[image]

2. Add `derived column` after source to add a **dummy** column with a **constant** value to later use it in Unpivot transformation.

[image]

**Derived column Data preview:**

[image]

3. Add `Unpivot` transformation after Derived column, to convert columns to rows. Under Unpivot settings

   a)    **Ungroup by:**  Select dummy column.

   b)    **Unpivot key:** Give a name to an unpivot column (Ex: Key), type as ‘string’.

   c)    **Unpivoted columns:** Give a column name for the data in unpivoted columns.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Unpivot Data preview:**

[image]

4. Add `Select` transformation after Unpivot to **remove** the **dummy** column and select only required columns to the output.

[image]

**Select Data preview:**

[image]

5. Add `sink` transformation at the end and connect to sink **delimited** **dataset**. In **Settings**, if you select the File name option as **Output to single file**, you can provide the sink file name.

[image]

**Sink Data preview:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of flatten transformation in data flow.
Please check the below Microsoft documentation page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you very much.